# функция в JS c If

Tags: javascript, if

> Создай функцию getLargestExpressionResult, которая принимает два числа a и b и возвращает наибольший возможный результат среди выражений:
>
> a + b
> a - b
> a * b
> a / b
>
> ограничения:
>
> Имей в виду, что a и b могут быть отрицательными.
> Не используй тернарный оператор или ключевое слово else.
> Не используй объект Math.

Почему-то у меня работает только сложение.

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * @param {number} a
 * @param {number} b
 *
 * @returns number
 */

// write code below this line
function getLargestExpressionResult(a, b) {
  if (a + b) {
    return a + b;
  }

  if (a - b) {
    return a - b;
  }

  if (a * b) {
    return a * b;
  }

  if (a / b) {
    return a / b;
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На этом сайте одновременно можно поставить только одну "галочку". Вернуть бы её первоначальному владельцу)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (a + b)`: a + b - некое число, а любое число в логическом контексте будет `true`, кроме числа `0`, вот почти всегда и возвращалось a + b.

> Не используй тернарный оператор или ключевое слово else. Не используй объект Math.

Так не надо делать, но язык позволяет:

1. Сортирует 4 числа по убыванию, берет первое. [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```
function getLargestExpressionResult(a, b) {
  return [ a + b, a - b, a * b, a / b ].sort( (a,b) => b - a )[0];
}
```

2. [Логическое "И"](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B) `&&`, вторая часть не выполнится, если первая окажется `false`

```
function getLargestExpressionResult(a, b) {
  let max = a + b;

  (a - b > max) && (max = a - b);
  (a * b > max) && (max = a * b);
  (a / b > max) && (max = a / b);
  
  return max;
}
```

3. [switch - case](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

```
function getLargestExpressionResult(a, b) {
  let max = a + b;

  switch (a - b > max) { case true: max = a - b }
  switch (a * b > max) { case true: max = a * b }
  switch (a / b > max) { case true: max = a / b }
  
  return max;
}
```

Comment: три switch?????

Comment: @Grundy Ну оно попадает под условие "не использовать else" ) C одним switch (true) не получилось: break нельзя, т.к. нужно проверить все три условия, а без break, после первого выполнившегося case, все остальные тоже выполняются независимо от их значений.

Comment: Почему `break` нельзя?

Comment: @Grundy Потому что https://jsfiddle.net/8bjpuodk/

Comment: Да, плохо что нет goto: https://jsfiddle.net/mr7dkLnv/

Comment: Так if же не запрещён.

Answer (score 5):

```
function getLargestExpressionResult(a, b) {
  let max = a + b;

  if (a - b > max) {
    max = a - b;
  }

  if (a * b > max) {
    max = a * b;
  }

  if (a / b > max) {
    max = a / b;
  }
  return max;
}
```

Вы же все время возвращали сумму и все. А нужно максимальное. Сначала записываем в макс одно из выражений, а потом проверяем остальные. Если кто-то больше, записываем его в макс.